# Chemical potential of a reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

I often see two various forms of the species $i$ chemical potential $\mu_i$ in a chemical reaction, in terms of enthalpy of formation $\Delta h_{f,i}^0$ and standard state entropy $s_i^0$.

My textbook says:

$$\mu_i = \Delta h_{f,i}^0 - Ts_i^0 + RTln\frac{P_i}{P_0} $$

But my professor wrote in class:

$$ \mu_i = \Delta h_{f,i}^0 + \int_{T_0}^T{c_{p,i}dT} - Ts_i^0 - T\int_{T_0}^T{\frac{c_{p,i}}{T}dT} + RTln\frac{P_i}{P_0}$$

where the extra integral terms come from the proper definition of $h_i$ and $s_i$. I therefore think my professor is correct, and the book is wrong. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Textbook is Sonntag's Fundamentals of Thermodynamics, 6th edition. I'm looking at Equation 15.10 on page 626.

Comment: Can you state which textbook are you using and refer to the relevant page? I suspect that the book defines $s^{0}_i$ as the entropy in temperature $T$, and similarly for $\Delta h^{0}_{\rm f, i}$ - which is exactly what you're saying.

Comment: @eranreches I updated the book and page number. I think the textbook was deriving $\mu_i$ at the standard state, so that $T=T_0$ like you said, but maybe I failed to see this. Does this mean enthalpy $h(T_0) = 0$ at the standard temperature?

Comment: Your book writes $\bar{h}^{0}_{ATP^{0}}$, so it explicitly states dependence on $T$. Note, in addition, that it derives this formula in the case of ideal-gas. Therefore, the enthalpy does not depend on $P$.

Comment: In my judgment, your professor is right and your book is wrong.

Comment: If you set $T=T_0$ both equations say the same thing. It appears then that the book gives the chemical potential at $T_0$,  $P$, and your teacher gives it at any $T$ and $P$.